# Transposing columns into rows in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a data set as follows:

| id | trouble |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | f |
| 3 | g |
| 3 | h |
| 3 | i |

But I need it as follows:

| id | trouble_1 | trouble_2 | trouble_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c |
| 2 | d | e | f |
| 3 | g | h | i |

Is there any tool that can do this? It is probably worth noting that `a` through `i` in the example are images, which may cause issues.

Comment: What type of data are you working with? Does "a through i are images" mean, you have images in the attribute table, or are you talking about links? Can you provide example data? What have you tried? How large is your data set?

Comment: For simple work there is a Group Stats plugin which can function like a pivot table if you don't want/need to do a full Excel type pivot table workup.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

### Solution 1: Excel

Export your data as CSV and do this operation in Excel: [Transpose data from rows to columns (or vice versa) in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-in-excel-for-mac-9c16dd55-ed1a-4aa2-8b74-b1b9211e2ede), the re-import to QGIS.

### Solution 2: QGIS

Use this expression to create an array of all trouble values for each group with the same id: `array_agg(trouble, group_by:=id)` - this returns like `[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`. Add the index of the element (0 for the first element in the array) in brackets `[]` to get the element.

- 1st element: `array_agg(trouble, group_by:=id)[0]`  -> `a`
- 2nd element: `array_agg(trouble, group_by:=id)[1]`  -> `b`
- etc.

Create a separate field for each of the elements or create a model to add all at once. Then delete duplicate features.

### Solution 3: QGIS (extended from solution 2)

1. Run [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) with `id` as `Group by expression` field
2. Run [Refactor Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisrefactorfields), delete/change the source expression and add new fields with names `trouble_1` to `trouble_3` and the source expression `string_to_array(trouble)[0]` to `string_to_array(trouble)[2]`.

It will create the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Nice to know my rough idea would have worked out.

Answer (score 6):

### Solution 3 : Full pure Python & PyQGIS

*See the code comments*

```py
from string import ascii_letters

ID, TROUBLE = range(2)

# create base layer
uri = "NoGeometry?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer&field=trouble:string"
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "base_layer", "memory")

feats = []
for i, trouble in enumerate(ascii_letters):
    if trouble == "j":
        break

    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setAttributes([i // 3 + 1, trouble])
    feats.append(feat)

with edit(lyr):
    lyr.addFeatures(feats)

# retrieve data
data = {}
for feat in lyr.getFeatures():
    attr = feat.attributes()
    if attr[ID] in data:
        data[attr[ID]].append(attr[TROUBLE])
    else:
        data[attr[ID]] = [attr[TROUBLE]]

# create new pivot layer
max_trouble_per_id = max([len(d) for d in data.values()])
trouble_fields = ""
for i in range(max_trouble_per_id):
    trouble_fields += f"&field=trouble_{i + 1}:string"

uri = f"NoGeometry?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer{trouble_fields}"
pivot_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "pivot_layer", "memory")

# add pivot features
pivot_feats = []
for id, troubles in data.items():
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setAttributes([id, *troubles])
    pivot_feats.append(feat)

with edit(pivot_lyr):
    pivot_lyr.addFeatures(pivot_feats)

# load the new pivot layer in the project
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(pivot_lyr)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here comes another PyQGIS solution.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'polygon'* with its attribute table, see the image below.

[image: input]

*Note:* Features with the same `"id"` possess the same geometry.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsAggregateCalculator, QgsFeatureRequest,
                       QgsField, edit)


def transpose_attrs_from_a_column(layer_name: str, declarative_field: str, target_field: str) -> None:
    """
    Transposes values into many fields from one field in the attribute table of a vector layer.
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param declarative_field: name of the supportive field e.g. "id", "fid" etc.
    :param target_field: name of the target field
    """

    # getting a layer by its name
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    # accessing all fields of the layer
    all_fields = layer.fields()

    # getting index of the target field
    target_field_index = all_fields.lookupField(target_field)

    # listing all values of the declarative field
    all_vals = layer.aggregate(
        aggregate=QgsAggregateCalculator.ArrayAggregate, fieldOrExpression=declarative_field
    )[0]
    # finding the most occurred value of the declarative_field
    most_occurred_val = layer.aggregate(
        aggregate=QgsAggregateCalculator.Majority, fieldOrExpression=declarative_field
    )[0]
    # counting how many times this value occurred
    times_occurred_val = all_vals.count(most_occurred_val)
    # getting a set of unique values
    unique_values = set(all_vals)

    # creating names for new fields
    new_fields = [f"{target_field}_{n + 1}" for n in range(times_occurred_val)]

    grouped_features = []
    grouped_vals_of_target_field = []

    # looping over each group of features united by the unique value in the declarative field
    for unique_value in unique_values:
        params = QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters()
        params.filter = f"\"{declarative_field}\"={unique_value}"

        # aggregating features "id"s of the original layer by the $id attribute
        aggregated_features_ids = layer.aggregate(
            aggregate=QgsAggregateCalculator.ArrayAggregate, fieldOrExpression="$id", parameters=params
        )[0]
        grouped_features.append(aggregated_features_ids)

        # aggregating features "id"s of the original layer by the target field
        aggregated_values_of_target_field = layer.aggregate(
            aggregate=QgsAggregateCalculator.ArrayAggregate, fieldOrExpression=target_field, parameters=params
        )[0]
        grouped_vals_of_target_field.append(aggregated_values_of_target_field)

    # getting indexes of features with unique geometries
    ids_of_unique_geoms = [group[0] for group in grouped_features]
    # getting a list with the required fields for the output
    required_fields = [field for field in all_fields.allAttributesList() if field != target_field_index]
    # creating a temporary layer for the output
    temp_layer = layer.materialize(
        QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(ids_of_unique_geoms).setSubsetOfAttributes(required_fields)
    )

    # getting data provider of the output layer
    temp_layer_provider = temp_layer.dataProvider()

    # creating new fields in the output layer
    for new_field in new_fields:
        temp_layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField(new_field, QVariant.String)])
    temp_layer.updateFields()

    # getting indexes of new fields in the output layer
    new_indxs = [temp_layer.fields().lookupField(new_field) for new_field in new_fields]

    # enriching each list with empty values
    for group in grouped_vals_of_target_field:
        group.extend([None for i in range(times_occurred_val - len(group))])

    # connecting new indexes with a group of values of the target field
    new_values = []
    for group in grouped_vals_of_target_field:
        new_values.append(dict(zip(new_indxs, group)))

    # editing the output layer
    with edit(temp_layer):
        for i, feature in enumerate(temp_layer.getFeatures()):
            temp_layer_provider.changeAttributeValues({feature.id(): new_values[i]})

    # adding the output layer to the map canvas
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp_layer)
    
    return

# applying the function
transpose_attrs_from_a_column('polygon', "id", "trouble")
```

Change the parameters of the function in the last line. Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

For simple work there is the ["Group Stats"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) plugin which can function like a pivot table if you don't want/need to do a full Excel type pivot table workup.